# How to write the symbols (↑, ↓, → and ←) in the sfml graphic library window?

Tags: sfml

[image]

Should another suffix be placed behind the text or do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vazir font doesn't support those characters, so, you need to use a font that supports those characters.
you may need to change the font to Fira-Code or something that you are already using in your VS-Code.

To find out which font is already being used in your vs-code, open `settings` in your vs-code, type in `font`, and look for the `font family`.

then search the internet, download that font, and load that font instead of Vazir.